# Getting value by name from OrderedDictionary

Tags: c#, ordereddictionary

I am looking for something like PHP's associative arrays that supports nesting too. For instance, I am creating a Dictionary Object like following:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary userRoles = new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary();
userRoles["UserId"] = "120202";
userRoles["UserName"] = "Jhon Doe";

// 2D array Like
userRoles["UserRoles"][0] = "CAN_EDIT_LIST";
userRoles["UserRoles"][1] = "CAN_EDIT_PAGE";
```

Then I would like to access them by KeyNames instead of index values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderedDictionary` uses objects for both keys and values.

To achieve nesting, just set the value to be another dictionary:

```
userRoles["UserRoles"] = new Dictionary();
```

Then you can use:

```
((Dictionary())userRoles["UserRoles"])["MyKey"] = "My Value";
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for. I think Looping thru will not be an issue either. Also my other part was How to access value by Name and Read it?